# Add @ Page attributes from code behind on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Long story short, a function on my page causes an error of "There is no MTS object context" when I try to execute it, without explicitly stating AspCompat="true":

< %@ Page Language="C#" AspCompat="true" %>

**My questions is is it at all possible to apply AspCompat="true" from code behind for the duration of the function and then remove it again (or not, I can simply redirect)?**

I need AspCopat NOT set to true at any other time BUT when the function is executed because it interferes with my Global.asax/Application_Error causing it not to fire at all, hence I can't error log properly.

(The function above needing aspcompat being true is a pdf generating 3rd party library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams not possible to achieve this.